# Pulling Content from Existing Database

Tags: custom-post-types, pages, database

I am moving an existing site to wordpress.

The existing site already has thousands of rows of data (items for a shop) stored in a different database. I dont want to import this data directly into wordpress as addtional data will be added to this pre-existing database.

What I would like to do is somehow be able to pull in the data from this external database via wordpress.

For example, if I accessed `www.site.com/shopping/345` this would pull in row 345 from my existing database.

Is this possible with a custom post type to map the existing content from my current database without having to create it all in wordpress too - or is there another way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Im not sure it's clear what you want to do, are you saying you want WordPress to show data, but that data comes from a remote/separate database or table that isn't a part of WordPress? Or are you saying that you want to import individual database rows on a per row basis as requested into WordPress' tables?

Comment: I want to make wordpress display data as if it were a post, but from a different database entirely. Something like an iframe loading the content would work, but I was wondering if there was a better way?